# How to store and step 12V to 5V with capacitor and regulator?

Tags: voltage-regulator

am a hobbyist with little prior electrical engineering knowledge so please bear this in mind! Trying to safely store and step down voltage from 12V to 5V using capacitors and L7805CV regulator.

Have been advised to follow the circuit for this below, however during testing there is a significant drop in voltage (measuring with multimeter at the points before and after C1 on circuit) and nothing appears to be getting to the 5V battery beyond the regulator.

[image: circuit]

**1. What is the correct schematic?** Since the above isn't working (preferable that circuit includes a voltage regulator and a capacitor)

**2. Are the capacitors in the right place / correct values?**

**3. Capacitor C1 discharges very quickly, why is this?** (>1 min charge goes down)

Thanks

*Edit: noticing a number of comments unrelated to the above three q's, which was why this post was created. To save time I will not be responding to unrelated comments. Cheers*

Comment: What do you mean by "measuring before and after C1" ?

Comment: And are you testing the schematic in simulation or have you actually made the circuit?

Comment: C1 is **tiny** for energy storage! Might be better to replace the 5v battery with a resistor that draws the amount of current you expect to want to source. It would make simulation, testing, understanding what's supposed to be happening a lot easier.

Comment: Hi CharlieHanson, measuring with multimeter at the points before and after C1 on the circuit

Comment: As in "to the left" and "to the right" of `C1`? They should all be the same voltage. Perhaps edit the picture to mark the exact points that you are measuring, and the voltages you get at each.

Comment: Unclear what "before and after C1" means; do you mean the multimeter (+) probe at different points along the +12V input wire to the 7805?

Comment: Might also help if you could post a photo of the actual prototype, since this is a very common type of circuit and it could either be a construction error or a measurement error.

Comment: Check the datasheet.  You need a 0.33µF from the 7805 input to ground, and a 0.1µF capacitor from the 7805 output to ground.  These two must be connected to the 7805 right at the 7805.

Comment: Hi Neil_UK, thanks for the info. C1 is a 47uF / 50V e.cap, can you suggest a more appropriate capacitor to use? Can't replace the battery component with a resistor as I'm trying to step down to a 5V battery

Comment: Also, check that (a) you have connected the pins correctly; and (b) if you are using a battery, check that it is charged, or consider a bench-type power supply.

Comment: Heat sinking will also be important; a 7805 is very inefficient at regulating 12V down to 5V. The heat loss will be (VIN-VOUT)*(whatever current the load draws). You may be surprised by how little load current it takes to make the bare 7805 really really hot.

Comment: You *can* replace the 5V battery with a resistor because it you are trying to get the circuit to work *in principle*. One step at a time.

Comment: And also, what 5V battery? I cannot right now think of a single rechargeable topology that's exactly 5V. Unless you mean a USB power pack, which will draw current to its own maximum until the voltage drops to 4.6V or so, which means the 7805 is _HEAVILY_ overloaded if the pack is limited at 2A or more.

Comment: Hi Asmyldof, yes it's a usb power pack, didn't know how to represent in a circuit. Do you recommend adding two 7805 components?

Comment: Are you trying to charge tell battery?  Why not ask how to do that?

Comment: Hi Scott Seidman, no. Is a usb power pack.

Comment: Maybe the cap is bad?

Comment: The circuit diagram is fine. The problem is probably in the way you've constructed it (strongly hinted at by your statement "there is a significant drop in voltage (measuring with multimeter at the points before and after C1 on circuit)". Post a few good hi-res photos from different angles of what you've actually constructed and we might be able to see what you've done wrong.

Comment: If something does not work, simplify.  My money is on 7805 pins.  Remove caps and load. Add a resistor as load.  Pin 1 to +12, 2 to gnd and 3 to +5V.  Verify operation.  Replace resistor with +5V load.  Verify operation.  2nd possibility, possible overload or thermal shutdown.  If you are creating a battery charger, then this is a definite possibility.  1.5A typical max for  TO220 package.  Finally, add caps, one at a time or all.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat agree. The above circuit looks way more complicated than it should be.

Answer (score 2):

> Capacitor C1 discharges very quickly, why is this?

Quiescent current (no load current) for a 7805 is about 5mA.

Q = CV or...

\$\dfrac{dQ}{dt}\$ = C \$\dfrac{dV}{dt}\$ = current

So 5 mA *\$\dfrac{1}{C}\$ = \$\dfrac{dV}{dt}\$ = 106 volts per second.

Or put another way, if you draw 5mA from a 47 uF capacitor charged to 12V, expect it to be fully depleted after 113 ms.

If instead of the 7805 you chose an LM2936 this time period would extend: -

[image]

Iq for this device is less than 15 uA for a no-load situation. This will extend the time period by about 333 times.